# react styled components not working in production

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have been able to work with styled-components on webpack dev server without any problem but the styles are not getting added when building the project for production with `webpack -p --progress --colors` or running `webpack -d --progress --colors --watch`

The only style added in production is an empty style

```
<style data-styled="" data-styled-version="4.4.1"></style>
```

in the webpack.config.js i have the following rules that is running for both dev and production:

```
module: {
    rules: [
     {
       test: /\.js?$/,
       exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
       loader: 'babel-loader',
       query: {
         presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
         plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties'],
       }
     },
    ]
```

},

Plugins, note that debug is used to if is production build

```
 plugins: debug ? [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'template.html')
      })
  ] : [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     "process.env": {
       NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
     },
   }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new UglifyJsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'template.html')
    })
  ],
```

dev server settings:

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: BUILD_DIR,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchContentBase: true,
    port: 9000
  },
```

Comment: There are not enough details. Please share your build/dev configs

Comment: @demkovych, i hope i added everything necessary without cluttering the post

Comment: Where is your styled-component babel plugin?

Comment: @demkovych i tried to installed 'babel-plugin-styled-components' before and added in `plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-decorators-legacy', 'transform-class-properties', 'babel-plugin-styled-components']` but still didnt work

Comment: please check [styled-components docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/tooling). There was described everything.

Comment: @demkovych i did that but it is not working. btw styled components not working ` webpack -d --progress --colors --watch`, only working in weback dev server

Comment: @demkovych i dont have babelrc in my project, is it needed or it is fine to add it in webpack config directly?

Comment: babelrc should be there, or inside package.json. I would recommend you to investigate already workings github repo examples, like https://github.com/radenkovic/styled-react-boilerplate

Comment: Few days back we even faced the same problem it got solved by upgrading react-scripts to "2.1.8".

Comment: i am not using react-scripts

Comment: @pabloBar If you add `optimization: {nodeEnv: 'prod'}` to your webpack config, the styles loads correctly? I need to add this in order to correctly display the styles but doing this raises other errors from other libraries that requires that NODE_ENV is set to production at runtime

Answer (score 6):

do you have a global style created with `createGlobalStyle` that contains a css `@import`? Removing the import from my site just fixed the issue for me. (sounds like the same issue).

https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/2911#issuecomment-592012166

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't necessarily understand why, but commenting out the @import and deploying again just made it work. I'm hosting a react app (built with create-react-app) on Heroku.

Comment: Hey, same thing... I might just move my global style to a css file for now. Thank you for that answer... time to sweep all the hair up.